# How to connect a swipe gesture to page control in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have page control that is set to show different images in the same view when you click the different dots on the page control. It works but you have to click on the ". . ." the first dot to see the first image, then the second to view the 2nd image, and the third to view the third. It is kind of hard to do for the user because the dots are so small. How do I get it to swipe instead of having to click on the dots?

Comment: checj this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990060/ios5-swipe-gesture

Comment: also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564153/how-to-add-swipe-gestures-to-uitableview-cell